# Unable to open page using displayDialogAsync

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js

I am trying to open our existing login page from our web app using displayDialogAsync but it returns 400 error.

```
var loginUrl =  'https://url.com/xxxxx/login.action';
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(loginUrl, {width:20, height:43}, function (asyncResult) {
loginDialog = asyncResult.value;
loginDialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, receiveMessage);
```

UPDATE: While debugging, i found [here](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-web-16.01.debug.js) in showDialog function where it added the pipes.

When i tried comparing the signin page of Dropbox, i noticed that the pipes were escaped.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. You mention a `|` but your sample code doesn't include one?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT i am talking about this parameter added into loginUrl once passed into dialog: __host_Info=outlook|web|16.01|en-us|783c4af8-1611-ccc4-6a56-df160b8e6f9a|isDialog_

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting back? There is normally an aditional messages with more specifics included in the error.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur-MSFT for your response. In Chrome i am getting: The page isn't working, HTTP ERROR 400. I have this error also when opening the addin _Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'ms-allow-popups' is an invalid sandbox flag._ , which i read from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221650/office-context-ui-displaydialogasync-throws-5001-internal-error) to just disregard it. While in IE the error is: _The webpage cannot be found. Most likely causes: There might be a typing error in the address.._ The async.status is succeeded and i am using O365 outlook.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT can i use our existing login page in our web app and open it using dialog or i need to create a new login page? What i am currently doing is the prior.

Comment: If you're calling a different domain for that page then you need to open a page within the add-in in the dialog first. You can then redirect that dialog to the other login. You only need your initial destination to be an Add-in page that includes an Office.initialize().

Answer (score 1):

Is the domain of your login page the same as the domain of the add-in's web application? Note the following:

> "the page, controller method, or other resource that is passed to the
>   displayDialogAsync method must be in the same domain as the host
>   page."

This is from [Use the Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

This means that the first page you open in the dialog has to be the same domain as the host page. But you can configure a script on that page to immediately redirect to a login page on another domain. When you redirect, the `_host_info` parameter will not be on the URL.

Comment: i am using the index.html as the host/landing page that has been created when i use the yeoman office-generator, therefore the domain of it is localhost. I only wanted to utilize the login page then the rest of the pages will be created inside the addin.

Comment: In your code line: var loginUrl =  'https://url.com/xxxxx/login.action';, is "url.com" the same for the index.html file and for what  you call the "login page"? If it is, and if the _host_info parameter is causing problems for your login page, then you can create a page with no UI that immediately redirects to your login page. Then pass the URL of the no-UI page to displayDialogAsync.